# Drupal 6 migrate to latest drupal 6

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, iis-7.5, migrate

Hello i have a problem migrating drupal core (drupal6)
After uploading all of my sites exept the main site show 404 not found.
Whats wrong?
I was reading a lot about htaccess but and rewrite base, but dont have any idea what to change.
Server is IIS 7.5 running on windows

Thanks in advance

Edit: I checked the applicationHost.config:

Maybe thats has something to say?

Edit: Maybe i need to say, that i was trying to upldate drupal local on an apache server, there its working fine, but i need to do it now on an iis server, maybe there is the problem, and don't realy get what i need to do with clean url, htaccess and rewrite mode. I enabled clean url in drupal, i checked htaccess, and i seems that it gets ignored, so is there  a need it shouldn't get ignored?
Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Have you carefully check your configuration using this guide ? https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls (see IIS section, for Drupal 7, but can be backported)

Comment: So i enabled clean url on my side. I read somewhere, that i need to check if my htaccess file gets ignored? So i added a string to that file, but the site still gets shown? So the htaccess file gets ignored, right? How to change that?

Comment: There is no .htaccess on IIS, you need to check the web.config file in your Drupal root

Comment: Thx, like u said, i need the web.config in the drupal root --> fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question got answered by the comment from @SebCorbin

There is no .htaccess on IIS, you need to check the web.config file in your Drupal root